# MySQLI query works on XAMPP but not on server

Tags: php, mysqli

My script is working fine on my local pc using XAMPP, but when I upload it to the server, 90% of the queries work, but this one is throwing an error (at the point it tries to bind the parameters):
"PHP Warning:  mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, bool given in..."

```
$sql = "WITH myscores AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY questionid ORDER BY myindex DESC) row_num, questionid, mark FROM quizscore WHERE userid = ? AND unitid = ?) SELECT questionid, mark FROM myscores WHERE row_num <=6";

   $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
            
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii", $userid, $unitid);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
```

If I simplify the SQL query then it no longer throws an error so I know my connection is okay (but it doesn't give me the data I need). Any help gratefully received. Thank you.

Comment: Most likely it's just mysql server mismatch. But to be sure, enable mysqli error reporting first

Comment: check which version the server actually has, if it has problems, it usually means you don't have mysql 8